# MSSQL - how to select several columns based on max id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

the result must be that for distinct `car_id` I want to select `max(exActId)` . `driver_id` and `contract_id` must be selected according to `max(exActId)` and `carId`.

result must be like

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Edit your question and show the sample data and desired results *as text* in the question.

Comment: Check out GROUP BY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`, although it is often more efficient to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.exActId = (select max(t2.exActId) from t t2 where t2.carId = t.carId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Group By based on `Max(ID)`
for example:

```
Select max(ID),name from TableName group BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE exActId IN (select MAX(exActId) from YourTable GROUP BY CarID);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT CAR_ID,DRIVER_ID,exActId,contract_id FROM 
    (
      SELECT CAR_ID,DRIVER_ID,exActId,contract_id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  CAR_ID,exActId ORDER BY exActId DESC) AS ro_NO FROM TABLE
    ) 
  WHERE  ro_NO =1
```